# Angular view isn't loading

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am not sure what I am doing incorrectly, but I cannot figure out why my `view` isn't loading.

I have this JavaScript:

```
angular.module('Console', ["ngRoute"]).config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/admin/leaderboard', {
        templateUrl: 'leaderboard.html',
        controller: 'MainContent',
        controllerAs: "app"
    }).otherwise({
        templateUrl: 'default.html',
        controller: 'DefaultCtrl',
        controllerAs: "app"
    });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}).controller('MainContent', function($scope){
    var self = this;
    self.message = "The app routing is working!";
    alert("I am running");
});
```

Working with this HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top: 15px;" ng-app="Console">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <ng-view></ng-view>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I load the page the alert displays, but the template doesn't load, an ajax request for the template isn't even made. Am I doing something wrong, or am I missing something?

Comment: You have duplicate `MainContent` controller instantiation, in `$routeProvider` and via `ng-controller`. Here should be one of that

Comment: I removed the one from the html, I thought that was binding the two together, so I guess not... I am still new to Angular.

Comment: Now you don't see your alert, it isn't? Do you have the proper url in address bar? Do you see an attempt to load `default.html` template?

Comment: Using html5 mode requires URL rewriting on server side. Have you done them?

Answer (score 1):

I got it, I needed to change this:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

to this:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: true,
    requireBase: false
});
```